# how do i add a UIView controller to a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uikit

i have a custom class of type `UIViewController`. i want to add it to a `UIView` so that it can be used to output to the screen.

the `UIView` is called engineView
my custom `UIViewController` is called Engine. there is a custom method in the controller called addImage.

the code is as follows:

```
Engine *engine = [[Engine alloc] init];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
engine.view.frame = frame;

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo2.jpg"];
[engine addImage:image];

[engineView addSubview: engine.view];
```

this does not display the image.

however if i add the view controller through storyboard, it seems to work (if i add the image at the `viewdidlayoutsubviews` method. but i would like to call functions to it programically from the parent `UIViewCcontroller`.

can anyone tell me how i do this?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can set storyBoard identifier in interface builder and ca use it like suggested above.

```
  MyViewController *instance = [self.storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourIdentifier"];
```

As far as adding a ViewController to UIView you can achieve that by using `addChildViewController`method too.

Answer (score 0):

try like this..

```
Engine *engine = (Engine *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EngineViewControllerStoryBoardID"];
```

to set the story board id
               [image]

to pass an image to Engine:

-->create a `UIImage` property  in Engine.h

like `@Property UIImage * engineImage;`

--> assign that image to `UIIMageView` in Engine.m

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{ 


    engineImageView.image = engineImage; // engineImageView is an example UIImageView replace it with your UIImageView

}
```

--> now send the image like
`engine.engineImage =[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo2.jpg`"];

Comment: i get the error: Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x10930a660>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'EngineViewControllerStoryBoardID'... i added this line by replacing the first line. is this correct?

Comment: i gave en example storyboard id(EngineViewControllerStoryBoardID) replace that with your storyboard id of EngineViewController

Comment: i no longer get that error, but i am still unable to add an image. how do i call methods within the engine class? [engine addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"];? this doesnt seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
 try this..

     Engine *eng=[self.storyboardinstantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourStoryboradId"];

*you can set storyboard id by going in Identity Inspector.
```

[image: Setting StoryboardId]
         After that You can add image on your View Controller by following code

```
        UIImageView *image=[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, your width, your Height);
        img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"];
        [eng addSubview:image];
```